# Running Svelte on Windows 10 - 'sirv' is not recognized as a command

Tags: windows, npm, svelte

I'm trying to get started with Svelte. All guides I've found list two commands as all that's required:

```sh
npm install
npm run dev
```

However, in Windows 10, with a fresh install of Node 12.16.3 LTS and NPM 6.14.4 ([installed with NVM-Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows) after uninstalling NodeJS completely, per [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/10549827)), once I hit `npm run dev`, I get the following errors:

```
$ npm run dev

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\SvelteTest
> rollup -c -w

'rollup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! svelte-app@1.0.0 dev: `rollup -c -w`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the svelte-app@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-23T02_58_39_101Z-debug.log
```

"Hmm... Okay, that's weird, since every tutorial I've watched and guide I've read has this including in `npm install`, but, no worries, I'll just install `rollup`," I think to myself... A quick `npm install -g rollup` later, and the error is fixed! Good start. Sadly, this doesn't last too long, since now I run into the following issue:

```
$ npm run dev

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\SvelteTest
> rollup -c -w

rollup v2.10.7
bundles src/main.js → public\build\bundle.js...
LiveReload enabled
created public\build\bundle.js in 338ms

> svelte-app@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\SvelteTest
> sirv public "--dev"

'sirv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! svelte-app@1.0.0 start: `sirv public "--dev"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the svelte-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-23T03_00_53_008Z-debug.log
```

This time, no amount of `npm install -g sirv` will work. Is there a step I'm missing to getting this project to run?

---

**Some notes:**

- I can get it to work in WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but would prefer not to have to use WSL if at all possible.

  - I don't see anything anywhere online that says that Windows isn't supported... is it not? Am I not looking hard enough?
- When I run `npm install -g rollup`, I see the following warnings:

  ```
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
  ```

  I assume that, since this is listed as an *optional* dependency, it is not the source of the issue. Nonetheless, it feels silly not to bring it up — just in case. These same warnings appear during `npm install`.
- The files `npm-cahce\_logs\[datetime]-debug.log` don't contain any usefull information as far as I can tell, they simply say, "`sirv public "--dev"` → `Failed to start exec script`" followed by a stack-trace.
- After the second error, the program does not automatically terminate — but it is not available at `localhost:5000`.
- I had my files in OneDrive for a while (they're now on my Desktop, which is not synced or tracked in any way), and OneDrive was upset about the files in `node_modules/.bin`, saying that they "couldn't be synced because of their name or type" -- this leads me to believe that perhaps this is a wider Windows/MS problem? Somehow, I doubt this is the issue.
- Just to double check, I tried all of my aforementioned steps in Git Bash (my preferred terminal on Windows), CMD, and Powershell -- all exhibited the same behaviour.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Installing it as a dev dependency fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, well... I feel silly now. Same issue as with Rollup — I had to install it with `npm` globally. But, I missed that there's both `sirv` and `sirv-cli` on NPM.

Running `npm install -g sirv-cli` fixed my issue.

However... I would still like to know why I don't see this issue mentioned anywhere in any guide anywhere else with all the rest of Svelte's *Hello World* stuff. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I looked at the 'official' svelte boilerplate and they have sirv-cli on the dependencies: https://github.com/sveltejs/template. But anyway: congratz that you found it and each error solved builds up experience :)

Comment: You shouldn't have to install things globally. Ordinarily, when you do `npm run [script]`, it prepends `node_modules/.bin` to your `$PATH` so that if the command references a local binary (like `rollup` or `sirv`) it will resolve to e.g. `node_modules/.bin/rollup`, which in turn is symlinked by npm to the relevant file. It sounds like that part of npm's behaviour isn't working for your particular setup

Comment: @RichHarris Thanks for the info! I'll look into that part more specifically.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown any chance you're using scoop.sh ? Because if you do it would be caused by scoop update which is what just happened here. Hope it helps.

Comment: @v01d No, I'm not, thanks, though :) I think whatever caused the issue was some anomaly with using Git Bash on Windows, which, in a recent update, introduced something along the lines of "closer emulation to Linux consoles" (I forget exactly what the option was, but the description was something along those lines). I went back and tried again without the global `sirv-cli` install, and it worked fine. Just worth noting that, at the moment, I think this is a beta feature of Git For Windows.