# what's the comand to know the Node.js version in angular's eyes(opinion)?

Tags: node.js, angular, apache-flink

when I do mvn compiling for flink source code，I get:

Node.js version `v9.0.3` detected.

The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of eithor `v10.13` or `v12.0`

---

when I input `node -v`, the result is `12.18`

so,what's the comand to know the Node.js version in angular's eyes?

and where does the old version `v9.0.3`  come from?

I restart my computer and the error remains.

Thanks for your help.

(Python3.6) appleyuchi@Desktop:~$ which  npm
/home/appleyuchi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin/npm

(Python3.6) appleyuchi@Desktop:~$ which nodejs

(Python3.6) appleyuchi@Desktop:~$ which node
/home/appleyuchi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.0/bin/node

I compile and get the following message again
Node.js version v10.9.0 detected.

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is here. Why do you think that the version of Node used by your install of Angular CLI **isn't** 12.18?

Comment: I have added something,thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You've got two different versions of node installed in different paths, and something about the process you use to "do mvn compiling for flink" is using the wrong one. Probably it is running as a different user with a different `$PATH`.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks...I forgot where they are....It seems that I have installed both in common user and root and ...um....I really forgot....

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by **angular's eyes?**  There is no different node  for angular. if it is installed then the node is same for all framework.

Follow this link to check Angular, Node.js and TypeScript compatibility.

https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

You can use nvm if you want to work with multiple node versions

this link will help in using nvm

https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

Comment: when I update my node with `g`,the old version remains when mvn compiling with angular command.

Comment: check this link https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3 to see if your angular is compatible and if not then install the node mentioned in the link

Comment: first uninstall the older node and delete temp file and then install new one

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies...I'm trying to make sure the node is deleted 100% now....

Comment: I have updated my statements...I have installed nvm.but the error remains.

Comment: try deleting directory where Node.js version v10.9.0 is installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows