# Peer dependency missing Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, npm, dependencies, vuejs3

Whenever i run `npm list -g --depth=0` command in cmd. I got this error from npm.

```
+-- @vue/cli@4.5.6
+-- typescript@4.0.3
`-- vue@3.0.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: vue@3.0.0, required by @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.0
```

I have tried different methods to fix this error.

I have also tried uninstalling and installing these packages.

I have also completely uninstalled node and installed it again [following this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows). After re-installing the packages, I still get this error.

Anyway to fix this error?

Comment: show your packages.json and `npm ls vue`

Comment: @Daniel These packages are installed globally. There is no package.json for global modules.

Comment: I have similar error,: `npm ERR! peer dep missing: prop-types@^15.6.0, required by react-ga@2.7.0` and it is not real problem. I can use npm withour trouble.

Comment: `npm ls vue`  -- vue@2.6.12 gives me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, Upgrade your **Nodejs to 15.5.1** & **npm to 7.4.0**. After upgrading, Use `npm list -g --depth=0` to check the error. The error will have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Il had the same Problem:

Remove all packages

- `sudo npm uninstall -g @vue` and
- `sudo npm uninstall -g typescript` also
- `sudo npm uninstall -g vue`

Make sure you delete everything:
`sudo apt remove npm` For Apt based Systems, `yum remove npm` for rpm based

Make sure no binary exists anymore for npm just an example
`npm version zsh: command not found: npm` 
Then i used snap [installation instructions](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd) to install the desired package (in this case 12):

Example:
`sudo snap install node --classic --channel=12`

Before you install it againt, follow the instructions here:[How to install global packages into own home dir](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92)

Then try again
`sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: I am on windows. I have tried by completely uninstalling node by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows. Even after that the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

As-of Jan 2021 the current (default) version of vue is 2.6.12. So by-default @vue/cli will download vue@2.6.12 into it's node_modules (sub-folder), and then complain about it.

To fix it, you can either (a) install vue@3 (as Daniel pointed-out) before installing @vue/cli or (b) cd into the @vue/cli folder, uninstall vue and (re)install vue@3.  You can also ignore that message because vue/cli will still run with vue@2.6.12.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix by

```
npm i -g vue@3
```

I fixed analogical error messages by command like this.

Other option is

```
npm remove -g @vue/compiler-sfc
```

Comment: I have also tried this method already. Even this cannot remove the error.

Comment: So try `npm remove -g @vue/compiler-sfc`. Or do it with `sudo` but if you need use sudo, you have badly configured npm.

Comment: I am on windows. I ran the `npm remove -g @vue/compiler-sfc` command but i am still getting the error.