# Npm ERR! Line breaks can’t be quoted on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

i have the following package.json code:

```
{
    "name": "pre-post",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "basic-server.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "ignore": "echo \"\" >> .gitignore",
      "preignore": "touch .gitignore",
      "postignore": "echo \".gitignore\n.vscode/\nnode_modules/\" >> .gitignore"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "linebreak": "^1.0.2",
      "open": "^7.4.0"
    }
}
```

after i run in node js command, i have the error message of `npm ERR! Line breaks can't be quoted on Windows`, any fix?

Comment: Update your node.js and npm version

Comment: all are most updated, even reinstalled node js

Comment: I have faced same problem. But node -v
v12.13.0 worked.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether your package.json have **swiper**

There are 4 steps to solve this problem

1. Remove **"swiper" : "^5.4.5"** from **package.json** file.(Check there should be **no comma** in last line of your json file)
2. Run **npm install** command in your terminal.
3. Run **npm install swiper** command.
4. Now you will see everything has been installed successfully.

Comment: Ohhhhh, great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't install it from Git Bash on Windows. Use cmd.exe and it works as a charm !

Answer (score -1):

1. Uninstall node.js from Control Panel/Programs
2. Download fresh node.js installer and install them.
3. (**important**) reboot system.

Answer (score -1):

### I face the same problem and this thing is work for me

1. Uninstall node completely use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/13791930)
2. reboot your device
3. download again from official website

Answer (score -1):

Use **yarn** to install the dependencies. Solved for me.