# react-native init or installation fail. npm ERR

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

At some point npm install won't work for my React Native applications and throws the following errors:

First, Globally installed packages:

[image]

Error I get:

```
C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev>react-native init MobileTrike
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

added 721 packages in 1m
info Setting up new React Native app in C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike
(node:14640) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Adding required dependencies
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.15.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Warning: Missing input files:
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libintl-8.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgthread-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
npm ERR! C:\GTK\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
npm ERR!   Backend.cc
npm ERR! c:\users\storm\onedrive\documents\_dev\mobiletrike\node_modules\canvas\src\backend\backend.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.1342) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\storm\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Dev\\MobileTrike\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.16.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.16.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\storm\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.16.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\storm\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Dev\\MobileTrike\\node_modules\\canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\storm\\OneDrive\\Documents\\_Dev\\MobileTrike\\node_modules\\canvas\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\storm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\storm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\storm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-04T05_03_33_843Z-debug.log
(node:14640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react@16.13.1
    at makeError (C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async generateProject (C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\initCompat.js:122:3)
    at async Object.initCompat (C:\Users\storm\OneDrive\Documents\_Dev\MobileTrike\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\initCompat.js:105:3)
(node:14640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14640) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have looked at Stackoverflow and GitHub threads, and **others seem similar but do not resolve my issue, and just causes other issues.** So i decided to post this question to show my specific problem.

A weird thing is that I have a previous application I made to replace a previous one but has a different problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470344/react-native-metro-is-path-is-missing-in-node-modules)

Edit: Added link to another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is a problem with node js and npm cache. Somehow I got stuck with a faulty version but for this solution.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) and follow the instructions there on clearing npm cache.

Make sure to restart your computer after following the process.