# react-native metro is path is missing in node_modules

Tags: react-native, npm

Error is this

```
Error: Unable to resolve module metro/src/lib/bundle-modules/HMRClient
```

Here is additional error logs
[image]

This error appeared when I had to create a new project and ran `react-native run-android` just right after running `react-native init PROJECT_NAME`. Why I had to create another project is due to another error shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468975/react-native-init-or-installation-fail-npm-err).

Now I can't seem to run any of my react-native applications due to these problems. I am thinking this is a cache problem or somethings? maybe unstable package versions.

I have also found this [solution in GitHub threads](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/540#issuecomment-524382413) and actually removed the error log, but keeps crashing my application in android emulator (android studio)

I have tried reinstalling react-native-cli, but still have this error.