# Cannot run any npm command after Node and npm upgrade

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

After upgrading to the latest Node and npm version, when I try any `npm` command, I get the following error:

```
 C:\Users\...>npm doctor
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of undefined
        at parseField (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\parse-field.js:15:43)
        at Config.parseField (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:438:12)
        at Config.[loadObject] (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:430:24)
        at Config.loadDefaults (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:268:22)
        at Config.load (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:207:10)
        at Object.[_load] (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:176:23)
    Error: call config.load() before reading values
        at Config.get (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:163:13)
        at errorHandler (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:179:32)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:42:14)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
        at Object.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:148:12
    Error: call config.load() before reading values
        at Config.get (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:163:13)
        at process.errorHandler (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:179:32)
        at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
    C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:163
          throw new Error('call config.load() before reading values')
          ^
    
    Error: call config.load() before reading values
        at Config.get (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\config\lib\index.js:163:13)
        at process.errorHandler (C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:179:32)
        at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:163:25)
```

Running command `npm -v` and `npm outdated`  returns the same error.

I run cmd as administrator.

**Environment Variables**

*User variables for ...*

[image]

*System variables*

[image]

Running command

```
C:\Users\...>node --version
```

returns

```
v14.16.1
```

I use Angular 7 and `ng build` seems to work as usual.

Comment: I tried to delete it but could not. I followed the recommended way (to edit the question) from the proposed article. Please let me know if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem. Be it any command, Node was throwing an error. After some research I found the solution which was a complete uninstall and removal of Node from my system and then a reinstallation of a fresh version.

Consider this answer to completely remove Node from the system:
[How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed Node from Apps&Features, but the error still remains the same. Also, cannot run step 1 of the recommended answer (npm cache clean --force).

Comment: Did you try removing the cache files? Also did you try changing the installation directory? Do update the PATH in env variables.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both, but nothing changed. I also tried to repair the Nodejs installation with no success. The problem was the npm folder inside node_modules. Hopefully, I managed to solve it by using another npm folder.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't have to re-install it, just change the node version with nvm.

some node version doesn't compatible with npm ver. ,

so first of all, check out your node version and then change your current node version to compatible with your npm version with node version manager(nvm).

Comment: You've assumed that node was originally installed using nvm, which is not necessarily the case.