# How can I solve a crash in an Adonis app starting?

Tags: node.js, npm, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

this is my first question ever. I'm trying to run an Adonis.js app by entering `adonis serve --dev` at the terminal. The messages are always the same in this succession:

> SERVER STARTED 
> Watching files for changes... 
> Fatal error in , line 0 
> Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status). 
> FailureMessage Object: 000000D7655ECBA0Application crashed, make sure to kill all related running process, fix the issue and re-run the app

The only thing that changes is the FailureMessageObject. My Node version is 12.0, npm 6.9.

Comment: Just to clarify I just crated the app with adonis new name-of-the-app. I haven't coded anything or changed the folders or something like that. It's the bare bones Adonis app created with the CLI.

Comment: Also, I've uninstalled Adonis globally and installed it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say anything seriously working on your situation cause you gave me no detailed data but I know that surely you are doing something wrong.
It could be better if you at least mentioned the version of adonisjs you've been using.
Anyway, if you learned to run your server from a video from someone else's youtube channel, I strongly recommend you to read documentation and stop watching those videos.
And for adonisjs there are 2 different documentation:

1. adonisjs's [Documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/installation), version 4.1 or less.
   You can change the version on top left combo box.
2. adonisjs's preview [Documentation](https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/quick-start), version 5.0.
   Actually the documentation is not still completed at this time but the version is stable. yeah, that's the reason why I wrote preview.

And that's it, start recreating an adonisjs app from documentation guides.

Comment: It was Adonis 4.1. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It was something with node or npm. I followed this steps enumerated in this post: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows). Reinstalled node. Installed Adonis and it's CLI again and created an app and this time the app didn't crashed, and ran smoothly (after that I also created some migrations and they too worked well).