# React: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-firebase'hooks' in 'C:\Users\<Name>\Web Dev\Firechat\firechat\src'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

So I am attempting to make a web app with React, Firebase, and the react-firebase-hooks module and I can't even get my code to compile. I have uninstalled react-firebase-hooks at least 3 times now and re-installed it just the same. I even installed it globally.
My output from npm list is:

[image: npm list]

Firebase resolves fine and there are no issues, so it can't be that something isn't installed. In my code, I am using:

```
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks';
import {useCollectionData} from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
```

To import useAuthState and useCollectionData from react-firebase-hooks.

Has anyone else had any issues with this? Is this some sort of compatibility issue that I'm not noticing? I also created a totally separate project running

```
npx create-react-app test
```

and then

```
cd test
```

followed by

```
npm install --save react-firebase-hooks
```

, imported the same 2 components from that module, ran my code with

```
npm start
```

and got the same error as I did in my actual app.

I also used

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and then ran

```
npm install
```

to no avail.

I am fairly new to the web dev world as well as React and Firebase so please forgive me if I'm overlooking something here.

Comment: I tried it, but wasn't able to reproduce the problem.  Try looking elsewhere.  Since it occurs on a new application, it's unlikely something to do with your code in the other application.  I find that restarting the computer works when nothing else does.

Comment: @ShamarYarde I didn't even think about restarting. I just went ahead and tried restart and no luck however.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by [completely uninstalling node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The useAuthState comes from "react-firebase-hooks/auth" modeule, that's why it's not working

Comment: I believe the video that I was following was just out of date. This is the answer!