# Node js - whenever I install a module, the cmd crashes

Tags: node.js

When I install a module and the screen says "completed" it stays hooked at this point.
As much as the node js process stops, the process does not stop and I have to restart the pc, however, I do not know if all the files were installed "correctly".

Whenever I create a project or something with "a command" of a module installed, the cmd also crashes, for example, in the case of my example: expo init my-app. (the command does not matter, it happens with any other command)

I put an image so that you can see exactly when it crashes, having to restart the pc.

[image - cmd hung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2BFO.png)

The process is hung
[image - service crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulHOm.png)

It's been happening to me since I installed node js.

I have even installed the latest version from the page.

I have tried:

```
1 - Reinstall
2 - Install the LTS / Current version (complete)
3 - Clear cache
4 - Uninstall using Node js:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows
5 - Regedit deleting it
6 - Go to the APPdata folder and delete your data
7 - Delete all modules
```

None of this worked.

I have tried from cmd (with and without privileges) from VSC (with and without privileges)

Is there any way that it won't hang after installing a module with the npm install?

**New update 1:11h am**

I have uninstalled node js again (deleting% appdata% npm folder) reinstalled it.

It happens exactly the same. I initialize the project and it gets "stuck"
[image - init proyect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPQZF.png), the service: [img - service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3udaA.png)
The folder weighs exactly the same since 10 minutes ago and has the same number of files.

This discourages me from continuing with node js. (this has been going on for 2 months) when I decided to use node js.

If I log out, I can't delete the node js project folder (it's like the process is hanging from the root). So I have to restart the pc.

Comment: It seems a mix, one image (cmd hung) is installing the expo-cli, which I assume is hung so it never completed.  Then another is using that expo-cli.  Did it finally finish?  Maybe a title change mentioning expo would be better, you're not just installing a module.  Can you create a new directory and do `npm init`, then `npm i express` or another module to see if it is just expo having problems?

Comment: That command for web has always worked for me. But not when I use others from other repositories with the structure "[command] init --..." For example, "expo init my-app", "spring init --..." or when I install some large package .. .

Comment: I don't know if this person has the same problem but it seems too much like my problem. I don't know if I should include it (the case is not solved)
https://githubmemory.com/repo/expo/expo-cli/issues/3787

Comment: No matter the module, I just tried: install --global expo-cli and it just "hung".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Deleting "all" the content of:

```
C: \ Users \ yourUser and default \ AppData \ Local
C: \ Users \ yourUser and default \ AppData \ LocalLow
C: \ Users \ yourUser and default \ AppData \ Roaming
```

After:

```
C: \ Users \ yourUser and default \
I deleted all the ".files" files
I also used: CCleaner (just in case)
```

And use the LTS version.
Although when I ran it from VSC it got stuck and I had to reboot. This has happened to me 2 times. (I have not tried it anymore). I don't recommend init [package] inside VSC, instead CMD or PowerShell.

Why did I delete them all? Because I knew that if I only deleted the node js files, it would not work (because I had already done this step before). It seemed silly and I was thinking about it while running my computer in safe mode to remove all references ... but it worked.

I advise:

- PowerShell (admin)
  For the installation of packages or projects even to run the server.
- VSC (admin) download a simple module or run a server.

It seems that there was some process between them that caused it to hang or call the same process / service. This gave me a lot of headaches (like resetting the taskbar, adding the shortcuts by hand ... a disaster). But it worked.

- You will have to reset your taskbar
- You will have to add the direct links in the taskbar
- Even delete the profile in regedit (it is simply looking for information about it)

Could this solution help? Could.
If you work with node js and you have this problem, first try to: delete only the node js folders from the sections that I have commented. If it doesn't work, you will have to delete everything I commented.

Now all processes work as they should.