# npm ERR! invalid options argument

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, npx, react-scripts

### Software specifications

| Software | OS | npm | npx | node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Version | Windows 10 | v8.1.2 | v8.1.2 | v16.13.1 |

I was following [this video](https://youtu.be/OH4msPNM2CI) and when I try to create a react application on my system by using the following command

```sh
npx create-react-app demo
```

It shows the following error:

```sh
npm ERR! invalid options argument

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-07T16_44_17_434Z-debug.log
```

### Log file's content

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v11.0.0\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'create-react-app',
0 verbose cli   'demo'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.2
2 info using node@v16.13.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hp\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 13ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
27 verbose stack TypeError: invalid options argument
27 verbose stack     at optsArg (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\lib\opts-arg.js:13:11)
27 verbose stack     at mkdirp (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:11:10)
27 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
27 verbose stack     at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
27 verbose stack     at Object.mkdirfix (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\cacache\lib\util\fix-owner.js:36:10)
27 verbose stack     at makeTmp (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\cacache\lib\content\write.js:121:19)
27 verbose stack     at write (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\cacache\lib\content\write.js:35:19)
27 verbose stack     at putData (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\cacache\put.js:11:10)
27 verbose stack     at Object.x.put (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\cacache\locales\en.js:28:37)
27 verbose stack     at WriteStream._flush (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\cache.js:156:21)
27 verbose stack     at WriteStream._write (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:36:35)
27 verbose stack     at doWrite (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:409:139)
27 verbose stack     at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:398:5)
27 verbose stack     at WriteStream.Writable.write (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:307:11)
27 verbose stack     at WriteStream.end (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:45:41)
27 verbose stack     at WriteStream.end (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\flush-write-stream\index.js:42:47)
28 verbose cwd C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop
29 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
30 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v11.0.0\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "demo"
31 verbose node v16.13.1
32 verbose npm  v8.1.2
33 error invalid options argument
34 verbose exit 1
```

Also tried running

```sh
npm i create-react-app -g demo
```

This resulted in the same error as above

### Tried Cloning and Running

I also tried to clone an already working react application, and when I ran the following command to install dependencies

```sh
npm i
```

This gave the following error:

```sh
npm ERR! invalid options argument

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-07T17_12_17_513Z-debug.log
```

When trying to clear the cache using `npm cache clean --force` the following error occurs:

```sh
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

Can someone help me understand what went wrong? Have I not done some installation correctly or missed out on any installation step? What can I do to get started with creating a react application on my machine? Any kind of help is appreciated. If you need any more information please let me know in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try completely removing npm and node like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) ? Seems to be an installation error. Also try to clean npm cache as indicated [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors).

Comment: I am unable to clear the cache. Tried running the command as administrator as well, it gave the same error as I have now included in my question.

Comment: Did reinstalling not fix the issue? Also the cache clean command seems to only have given a warning and not an error, so it might have run successfully. Try creating the react app again? If all else fails I guess you could try an older version of node and npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that of an inappropriate installation. The go to way to fix this would be to ensure a proper uninstall of `node` and `npm`. Please follow the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/17623273).
Once properly uninstalled, head over to [install node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and proceed with the re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but using the arch linux operating system, this has not so much to do with whether you have done the installation well or not, sometimes some modules can interfere with each other due to compatibility issues.
In my case when I tracked the error, the error was in /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/***. Although I uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs and npm it was not solved, so I decided to delete the node_modules folder completely once uninstalled node and then reinstall it.
In your case with Windows, the error sends you to the folder C:\UsersAppData\Roaming\nvm***. So I recommend you to uninstall nodejs and delete the nvm folder completely, since it is the one that is causing the error.