# npm install command manipulates package-lock.json with unrelated packages and package versions

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I am working on a project with OpenAI API and while it works fine on laptop it's not working on my desktop.

I cloned my project from git then I used npm install command after npm init command. When I use npm install npm didn't throw any err or warning and manipulated my package-lock.json as below

```
{
  "name": "open-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "open-api",
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "express": "^4.18.0",
        "openai": "^2.0.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {}
    },
    "ode_modules/accepts": {
      "version": "1.3.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PYAthTa2m2VKxuvSD3DPC/Gy+U+sOA1LAuT8mkmRuvw+NACSaeXEQ+NHcVF7rONl6qcaxV3Uuemwawk+7+SJLw==",
      "extraneous": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "mime-types": "~2.1.34",
        "negotiator": "0.6.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "deep-equal": "1.0.1",
        "eslint": "7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "14.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
        "eslint-plugin-markdown": "2.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "4.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "4.1.0",
        "mocha": "9.2.0",
        "nyc": "15.1.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.6"
      }
    },
```

while my original code in package-lock.json was exactly like this

```
{
  "name": "open-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "open-api",
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "express": "^4.18.0",
        "openai": "^2.0.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {}
    },
    "node_modules/accepts": {
      "version": "1.3.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PYAthTa2m2VKxuvSD3DPC/Gy+U+sOA1LAuT8mkmRuvw+NACSaeXEQ+NHcVF7rONl6qcaxV3Uuemwawk+7+SJLw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "mime-types": "~2.1.34",
        "negotiator": "0.6.3"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.6"
      }
```

package.json if you need to look out;

```
{
  "name": "open-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "openai": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Because of this manipulation npm didn't install any node_modules and always manipulates package-lock.json with "ode_modules", "de_modules" or "_modules" named dependencies and I don't understand why there isn't any err messages to figure out this problem.

I tried to;

- Delete package-lock.json and npm install again
- Install all packages with npm install "package name" for each manually but versions returned in dependencies as  "*"

```
  "name": "open-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  },
```

- npm install --verbose didn't find any errors in logs

```
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.5.5
npm info using node@v16.15.0
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:F:\Programlar\İş\Denemeler\OpenAI\server\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Murat\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 12ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 14ms
npm verb logfile C:\Users\Murat\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-01T13_46_15_241Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 6ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 35ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 31ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
npm verb shrinkwrap failed to load ode_modules/.package-lock.json missing from lockfile: ode_modules/accepts
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cors 522ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv 133ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express 6ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/openai 938ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition 75ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser 78ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts 79ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vary 81ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie 82ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature 83ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type 86ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/encodeurl 85ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten 90ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html 89ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/depd 91ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler 91ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors 91ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-errors 94ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh 95ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/etag 97ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished 98ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl 97ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods 100ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp 99ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 107ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr 101ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer 100ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs 101ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send 101ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses 100ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser 104ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static 103ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is 103ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge 104ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/setprototypeof 109ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign 183ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data 418ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 439ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 2078ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/cors Completed in 2ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/dotenv Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/toidentifier 34ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes 40ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types 42ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe 41ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite 46ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy 47ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator 49ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first 44ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body 49ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js 46ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits 49ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 50ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/side-channel 49ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded 55ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer 54ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime 57ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/express Completed in 101ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db 4ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/accepts Completed in 8ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/array-flatten Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer 4ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/body-parser Completed in 16ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/bytes Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/content-disposition Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/content-type Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/cookie Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/cookie-signature Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/debug Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/destroy Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/encodeurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/escape-html Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/etag Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/finalhandler Completed in 5ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/debug Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/encodeurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/escape-html Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/fresh Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/http-errors Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/iconv-lite Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/inherits Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/merge-descriptors Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/methods Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-types Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-db Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/negotiator Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/object-assign Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/on-finished Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ee-first Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream 138ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asynckit 140ms (cache revalidated)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/follow-redirects 935ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/openai Completed in 937ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/axios Completed in 2ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/follow-redirects Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream 149ms (cache revalidated)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/form-data Completed in 153ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/asynckit Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/combined-stream Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/delayed-stream Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-types Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-db Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/parseurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/path-to-regexp Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/proxy-addr Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/forwarded Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ipaddr.js Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/get-intrinsic 9ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/call-bind 11ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-inspect 11ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/qs Completed in 15ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/range-parser Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/raw-body Completed in 4ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/bytes Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/http-errors Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/iconv-lite Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/inherits Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/safe-buffer Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/safer-buffer Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/send Completed in 12ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/debug Completed in 2ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/destroy Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/encodeurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/escape-html Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/etag Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/fresh Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/http-errors Completed in 5ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/inherits Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/on-finished Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ee-first Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/range-parser Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/serve-static Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/encodeurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/escape-html Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/parseurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/send Completed in 7ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/debug Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/destroy Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/encodeurl Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/escape-html Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/etag Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/fresh Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/http-errors Completed in 5ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/depd Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/inherits Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/on-finished Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/ee-first Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/range-parser Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/setprototypeof Completed in 0ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has 7ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-symbols 7ms (cache hit)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/function-bind 9ms (cache hit)
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/side-channel Completed in 13ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/call-bind Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/function-bind Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/get-intrinsic Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/function-bind Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/has Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/function-bind Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/has-symbols Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/object-inspect Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/statuses Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/toidentifier Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/type-is Completed in 2ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/media-typer Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-types Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/mime-db Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/unpipe Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/utils-merge Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:ode_modules/vary Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 3438ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 3472ms
npm timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 3473ms
npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:createSparse Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 1ms
npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 0ms
npm timing build:deps Completed in 0ms
npm timing build Completed in 1ms
npm timing reify:build Completed in 2ms
npm timing reify:trash Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:save Completed in 11ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 354ms
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 357ms
npm timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:audit Completed in 358ms
npm timing reify Completed in 3844ms

up to date, audited 67 packages in 4s

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm timing command:install Completed in 3851ms
npm verb exit 0
npm timing npm Completed in 4132ms
npm info ok
```

- Delete node and npm completely as described here [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

None of those worked for me is there any solutions for this?

P.s: yarn install worked properly but this isn't a solution in my case, I need to work with npm

Comment: A solution for what problem?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, logs, error messages or configurations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by changing the parent-folder name and it started to work correctly, IDK what exactly happened but if anyone facing similar problem that's worked for me!

Please let me know your thoughts about what might be happened, thank you in advance!