# NPM - ENOENT syscall spawn bash (this is related to npm not being able to find a file)

Tags: node.js, npm

## Overview

I am attempting to troubleshoot why I can't run `scripts` defined in a `package.json` file via [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script) command.  Every script command returns the same error message:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT 
> npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
> npm ERR! path C:\Temp\test4
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

## Minimal Repro Steps

I installed NodeJS 18.12.1 x64 MSI from the [Node Download Page](https://nodejs.org/en/download) on my Windows 11 machine.

I created an empty directory (called **test4** in my example here) with a single file called `package.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "hello": "echo 'Hello World'"
  }
}
```

I opened a PowerShell window as administrator inside the same folder as the `package.json` file listed above.

Running `npm run hello` generates the error message above.

## Verbose/Silly Logging Results

One troubleshooting techniques I used was to enable [silly logging](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/logging?v=true#aliases) to log as many details as possible.  The results of that command (`npm run hello -ddd`) are below:

[image: Screenshot of detailed logging]

## Expected Behavior

I had a colleague attempt the same step and he was able to get the results I anticipated:
[image: Screenshot of command working]

## Things I Have Already Tried

- Completely uninstalling NodeJs/NPM following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/2494785)
- Installing different version of NodeJS/NPM.  (I tried 2/3 different versions)
- Running `npm install` on my simplistic `package.json` file above and on a 'real' `package.json` file from one of my projects.  Both projects install successfully.
- Reviewed the log file mentioned in the error message referring to the AppData folder.  (It's the same content as the verbose error screenshot I provided above)

Answer (score 9):

Run `npm config list` and check if `script-shell` is set:

[image: npm config list results]

In my case, it was configured to use `bash`, which is why the error was happening.  To solve this, simply remove the configuration setting by running `npm config delete script-shell`

As to why/how this got set, I am unsure.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. You could also remove the `script-shell = "bash"` line from .npmrc file in your windows user root.

Comment: god I could not use npm for a month because of this error, thank you