# Unable to create lockable file error after running Vite dev server with Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, caching, vite

Ok bare with me please. When running Vite in my Laravel 10 installation with `npm run dev` the API call's of my webapp run into the following error:

`Unable to create lockable file: C:\Websites\website.nl\storage\framework/cache/data/03/bc/03bc23b61d4cf128f2bd79541d52e1b98f18c79d. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location.`

I am running on Windows. But I can use the `bash` command that brings me to a Linuxy place thanks to WSL... But I am not sure if that means if I can just do commands like `chmod` there. It is kinda new to me.

In short: When running the ViteJs dev server the file permissions are incorrect in the `storage` folder.

I tried giving the chmod 775 to the storage folder (via the bash command). And also tried to change the owner of the storage folder and subfolders to www-data.

All to no avail.

So how to fix this error in Windows? Thanks!

BTW: this happens only when running the ViteJs dev server. I also can't run `php artisan cache:clear` when running the ViteJs dev server.

Then I will get this error:
 `ERROR  Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions.`

**UPDATE:**
After testing for a while I noticed that this problem accurs after like a minute or so of refreshing pages with Vite and hot reloading. After a minute the `1` of the file changes to a `0`. See picture below.

[image]

Comment: Try `777` not `775` that is not full permissions for a process outside the linux's user or group. Only do this on development

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: are you running a docker instance or is it pure WSL?

Comment: I'm running Xampp. Not Docker.

Comment: I can't imagine Linux permissions would have any effect on Windows files. If the web server is running in Linux, the files should be in the Linux filesystem. If the web server is running in Windows, you'll need to address permissions there.

Comment: @Floris do not mix windows with WSL, if you want to run stuff from WSL have the files in WSL (not `mnt`), you will always have this issues then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to remove WSL from Windows (via the optional Windows features removal of Windows). Then the `bash` command gave errors in ViteJs. So I applied [the solution mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635083/npm-enoent-syscall-spawn-bash-this-is-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a). And finally I removed the package-lock.json, the `node_modules` folder and ran `npm i`.

NOW everything works fine.