# Cannot run any npx command

Tags: npm, npx

Every time I run any `npx` command it gives me an error with the following message:

```
npx create-expo-app myApp
```

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Name\Documents\Programming\ReactNative
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I tried clearing the npm cache, but that didn't helped.

Comment: This looks like your NPM thinks your shell environment is bash, which is probably not correct as the path looks like you're on a Windows machine.  Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74647007/507793 for more details.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you very much. I have been looking for a solution for hours. :) @Matthew Do you want to add your comment as a Answer? Then I can accept it! :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it looks like npm thinks your shell is `bash`, hence the `npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT` error.  From the "path" in the error message, I'll assume you're working in a Windows environment, where `bash` is likely not available.

You can see what your shell is by executing `npm config ls -l` and looking for the `script-shell` value.

See answer [NPM - ENOENT syscall spawn bash (this is related to npm not being able to find a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635083/npm-enoent-syscall-spawn-bash-this-is-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a/74647007#74647007) for more details.