# Error running npx after installing specific version of node on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npx

I installed 18.12.1 version of node (the latest at the time), after I discovered that the web application I was building, needed an older version of node. So I tried to install nvm to manage different versions, but being beside a proxy company is not easy. So I uninstalled node and nvm, and installed node 12.22.12, because in a coworker laptop it works fine with this.
After launching `npm install`, I launched `npx webpack --mode none` but I get this errors (I removed some of them):

```
[54] ./src/pages/le-tue-dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-list/dichiarazioni-list.jsx 329 bytes {1} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[55] ./src/pages/dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-page/dichiarazioni-page.jsx 1.35 KiB {1} [built]
[59] ./src/css/app.css 39 bytes {1} [built]
[60] ./src/logo.svg 44 bytes {1} [built]
[61] ./src/App.css 39 bytes {1} [built]
    + 599 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/pages/riepilogo/persona-giuridica-fourth-step-dichiarazioni/persona-giuridica-fourth-step-dichiarazioni.jsx 100:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       errors: {},
|       errorsBkp: {},
>       frontespizioIniziale: this.props.history?.location?.state?.frontespizioIniziale != null ? this.props.history.location.state.frontespizioIniziale : {},
|       datiContribuente: {
|         isPersonaFisica: false
 @ ./src/pages/riepilogo/riepilogo-for-list.jsx 16:0-144 168:41-80
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/pages/le-tue-dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-list/dichiarazioni-list.jsx 103:44
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (103:44)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             lgth: res.result.length,
|             isLoading: false,
>             elencoDichiarazioni: res.result?.splice(index, this.state.Pagination.limit)
|           });
|         } else {
 @ ./src/App.jsx 14:0-105 296:55-74

ERROR in ./src/pages/riepilogo/tipo-contribuente-ninth-step-dichiarazioni/tipo-contribuente-ninth-step-dichiarazioni.jsx 111:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (111:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   handleInputChange(event) {
|     event.preventDefault();
>     const target = event?.target;
|     const value = target?.type === "checkbox" ? target?.checked : target?.value;
|     const name = target?.name;
 @ ./src/pages/riepilogo/riepilogo-for-list.jsx 13:0-141 178:41-79
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/pages/riepilogo/versamenti-tenth-step-dichiarazioni/versamenti-tenth-step-dichiarazioni.jsx 118:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (118:41)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|             id: "estremiVersamento",
|             name: "estremiVersamento",
>             value: this.props.versamento?.estremiVersamento,
|             label: "Estremi del/i versamento/i: (1800 caratteri)",
|             error: touched.estremiVersamento && errors.estremiVersamento,
 @ ./src/pages/riepilogo/riepilogo-for-list.jsx 14:0-121 180:41-73
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/pages/dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-page/dichiarazione-pf-pg/dichiarazione-pg/dichiarazione-pg.jsx 120:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (120:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       errors: {},
|       errorsBkp: {},
>       frontespizioIniziale: this.props.history?.location?.state?.frontespizioIniziale != null ? this.props.history.location.state.frontespizioIniziale : {},
|       datiContribuente: {
|         isPersonaFisica: false
 @ ./src/pages/dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-page/dichiarazione-pf-pg/dichiarazione-pf-pg.jsx 8:0-66
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/pages/riepilogo/annotazioni-generali-eleventh-step-dichiarazioni/annotazioni-generali-eleventh-step-dichiarazioni.jsx 131:35
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (131:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
|           className: "form-group"
>         }), this.props.annotazioni?.length != 0 ? this.props.annotazioni.map((element, index) => /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
|           className: "form-group",
|           key: index
 @ ./src/pages/riepilogo/riepilogo-for-list.jsx 6:0-159 182:41-85
 @ ./src/App.jsx

ERROR in ./src/pages/dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-page/dichiarazione-pf-pg/dichiarazione-pf/dichiarazione-pf.jsx 132:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (132:47)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       capSedeItaliaPNF: "",
|       statoSedeEsteroPNF: "",
>       frontespizioIniziale: this.props.history?.location?.state?.frontespizioIniziale != null ? this.props.history.location.state.frontespizioIniziale : {},
|       datiContribuente: {
|         isPersonaFisica: false
 @ ./src/pages/dichiarazioni/dichiarazioni-page/dichiarazione-pf-pg/dichiarazione-pf-pg.jsx 9:0-66 25:44-59
 @ ./src/App.jsx
```

On another coworker laptop with `node 12.14.1` it runs without errors too, so I tried to uninstall and install this version and launch `npm` and after `npx`, but on the `npx` I get the same errors.

So I made a new attempt using another laptop with no node installed. There I installed the 12.14.1, and the `npx` command run without errors there too.

I checked my environment variable, but I didn't find anything noticeable. The attempts that I made was done with new "fresh" code downloaded from the repository in a new folder, just to be totally sure to not have some temporary file in the project.
After several uninstall now launching `node -v` it says: v12.22.12 and `npx -v` says: 6.14.16

I run out of ideas, what do you suggest to do now?

Comment: Uninstall node and nvm was not enough. I needed a [total remove of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711410/1878854)