# how to fix a problem with a corrupted version of node nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I researched a lot on the subject, but I couldn't find a viable solution to my problem, I'm setting up a development environment by NVM I installed node 8.9.0, I managed to install the NPM package on it and the grunt libraries I needed, however, now I'm trying to do the same procedure, but in version 4.4.0 and it doesn't work, any command I give in version 4.4.0 doesn't return any errors

I already tried all the steps in this tutorial: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)
but it didn't solve my problem either

on another clean machine I installed node 4.4.0 before version 8.9.0 and it worked normally, but it seems that having installed version 8 before version 4 generated this problem

problem image link: https://ibb.co/SQjR9Wz

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)