# I somehow have multiple Node Versions Installed (have 20.10.0 but says 17.1.0 when I try to install). Sveltekit Reference Error: Request is not define

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, npm-install, sveltekit

Here is what it looks like when trying to create a Next.js project:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when trying to create and run a Sveltekit project:
[image]

I am still able to run older projects that I have worked on and create client side react and svelte projects.

Could it be a different account on my laptop? Is there any way to recursively look for npm/node installs on my laptop and completely wipe them?

I have tried to use the steps from here twice: [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

I have wiped my computer completely of node to the point where node -v and npm -v don't work and then reinstalled the LTS. Somehow when trying to run server side frameworks with npm I keep getting version incompatibility which makes no sense to me. I am at the point of completely wiping my drive and starting everything over.