# Quick delete remote directory

Tags: java, filesystems, cifs

We writed java program, it deletes directory on some shared network disc. But it is very slow. It uses recursion for directories deletion (in function commons-io FileUtils.deleteDirectory). But I think recursion is slow, because there is a lot of network communication.

Is some way, how to delete directory with content by one "command"?

Comment: Have a look at [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and its method [`walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor))

Comment: Thanks deHaar, but I do not want to walk file tree and delete individual files. I think it is slow. I would like to send one delete command to other system. For example in webdav it is one command delete, which deletes directory and its content (http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#delete-collections). I hope, that it is possible with windows shares (CIFS protocol) too. But I don´t know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use commands

**del /f/s/q foldername > nul**

**rmdir /s/q foldername**

on Windows, i.e. we call theese commands from Java.

See [What's the fastest way to delete a large folder in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186737/whats-the-fastest-way-to-delete-a-large-folder-in-windows/6208144)

It isn't too nice, but it works :-).