# I accidentally changed a high-level directory on my computer into a source control repository using VS Code. How can I undo this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

I somehow managed to add every single file on my laptop to the version control bar in Microsoft visual studio. As a result there are tens of thousands of files in the version control bar, which has completely slowed down my laptop and caused it to turn off several times.

I tried discarding all the files in the version control bar. This hasn't worked for 2 reasons:

1. There are far to many files.
2. Some files yid errors meaning they can't be discarded from the version control bar.
   I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code but that did nothing.

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore?

Comment: @JesusFung This happened when I was trying to learn how to use version control so I'm not sure what a .gitignore is and I don't have one configured

Comment: ok. To understand more, what is the "version control bar" and what are you trying to accomplish (push files to repo, clone repository?)

Comment: @JesusFung: I added my home directory i.e. C:\Users\name to the source control bar in VScode. I want to clear it

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Git repository that you created, find the .git directory for the repo (directly under the root directory of the repository) and delete it (see also [What is the .git folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29217859/11107541)). On Unix, one efficient way is to use `rm -rf` (make absolutely *sure* you pass the right path). If you're on windows, see [What's the fastest way to delete a large folder in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186737/11107541).