# VS-Code Source control issue..git repository at "c:\Users\HP" has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, repo

Why are there 10000 files/changes and do I even need them
??there are 10000 active changes in the git repository. I tried deleting this, but I think that this may lead to any errors. Do I even need these files? This is the error it shows everytime I open vscode- git repository at "c:\Users\HP" has too many active
changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.
Tell me if I can delete these changes that is these files or some other way to stop this.

Tried discarding all changes.

[image]

Comment: do an SO search for `10k git`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410189/11107541

Answer (score 1):

You've created a Git repository in your home directory instead of a subdirectory that contains your project.  As a result, when VS Code tries to monitor the files for changes, it runs out of resources.

In general, unless you are very certain that you know what you're doing, you should not make your home directory a Git repository.  Instead, move the `.git` directory in your home directory to `.git.bak` (using a POSIX shell, such as Git Bash on Windows) using `mv .git .git.bak`, and then switch to your project directory with `cd` and run `git init` in that directory to create a new repository.  Don't run `git init` in your home directory, because that will create the same problem.  Then, reload your editor, and the problem should go away.