# VS Code suggest me to upload all my user Data to github

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, commit

Every time i open VScode a notiffication appears "The git repository at "c:\Users*****" has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled."

i tried to use this solution https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38173

but i cant see the .git folder inside of my user folder. I tried to use the terminal but it says that i dont have permission to deleate it. So i typed on the file finder "c:\Users*****.git" and the folder was open with a folder called "objects" and inside of it more folders like "48" "e0", etc. and some documents too.

But i couldnt deleate the folder named ".git" i cant see it and i tried to deleate it again with the terminal and it says i dont have the permission to do it.

Good news is that when i open VS code now it dosent suggest me to commit the changes in user**** but idk if the solution i found its gonna give me some problems or what.

ok so basically i did what i said before, triied to deleate .git file inside my user in the PC. But im not sure if my solution is gonna give me further problems or what.

Comment: If you delete the `.git` folder then your project is no longer version controlled. Is that what you want?

Comment: you don't have permission to create/delete files/folders in your home directory

Comment: It sounds to me like you have accidentally created a git repository in a location you didn't mean to, which is now tracking a VERY large amount of files that are not meant to be inside your project. In order to delete your folder, you need admin rights. But as @JohnKugelman said, is that what you want?

Comment: potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410189/11107541