Cant commit changes in vscode git
Im beginner in programming and I am writing a project in vs code and trying to commit new files to synchronize with my github.
But 10,000 files in the directory are writing to me C:\Users\gerga.DESKTOP-BSQOQP7 .
I tried to do everything reinstalled.
How do I get git to sync files in my folder and not in another one
I tried to change the folder from where 10,000 comments come from my user folder, I tried to clone to a work package on the desktop. I tried to reinstall git, nothing worked

Which directory did you open in vscode? It should only display changes, if you have opened a directory which is a git repository (has a .git folder). It shouldn't be possible to show changes outside that repository.

probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410189/11107541

Looks like you are missing .gitignore
Go to: https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/.
and generate the ignore file.
Once generated save it in your main folder as .gitignore

so, I created  gitignore file in the github repo  then i copied repository to a folder on the desktop. and in C:\Users\gerga.РАБОЧИЙ СТОЛ-BSQOQP7   deleted the folder.git . Now there are no changes anyway
