why the vscode's git indicates that more than 10000 files are changed
the curretn situationRecently installed npm and node.js. And also yesterday tried to push some codes to the github but failed, maybe mistakenly pushes all files from the desktop to github but failed. Then yesterday suddently the git indicates "Too many changes are detected. Only the first 10000 changes will be shown below." And when I check the changed files, I  found even files stored on my desktop are all listed as changed files in vscode. And it seems like it lists all files on the desktop in the changed files list. And I did not even create any repositories for it yet. Can someone help me resole it? The attched is the current situation. But I can't delete the changes, since I will lose all the files within the laptop on the desktop when deleting them.
Did anyone know how to clear them?

well, does your GitHub account have a repository showing all those files? If yes, you can delete the .git from your VS Code and also this repository from your GitHub account

I have already deleted the repo I created. But that did not work.

But did you also remove the local, hidden .git folder?

where is the .git folder

one thing I have to say is that I did not the "git init" any repo in my local laptop. In just simply opened the folder in vscode. Thus right now when I checked the source control repo, it says is /User/...

Maybe here is the problem

have you done a search on SO for visual-studio-code 10k

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76410189/11107541
